# How to customize master template concept in codeigniter 3.0?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in Codeigniter 3.0. So master page concept how used in Codeigniter 3.

I want to make the admin panel master page so I don't rewrite header, footer code. I also want to customize the title.

How to do it?

Comment: 1) I've tried to give to your post a better form, but it seems still unclear to me. It is important to try to use clear sentences, and try to follow the style of the English communication. Give also many details: explain, what you tried, what problems you found, what is not working. People here can see only what you write, they don't see what is on your computer. 2) It is not a problem if your English is not very good, the problem is if people doesn't understand what you ask.

Comment: what not understand ?? its simple how make layout

Comment: header , footer , sidebar , content i want this fout layout ok ??

Comment: i want customize like in <title></title> not same all page

Comment: [Learn to use at least the shift key...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370)

Comment: when click on dashboard then <title>Dashboard - Admin Panel</title> other when click profile then <title>Profile - Admin Panel </title> etc

Comment: Well, now I understand that your problem lies deeper as the nearly perfect lack of English. It seems, you are somehow unable to understand what I am writing to you. Did you read the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would create something like this below in a controller. You can set your content page in a variable like below and then pass it to your admin template. Like in the example view. Just a example below though. also auto load url helper.

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {
      // You should be able to pass data as normal

      $data['title'] = 'Welcome to CodeIgniter'; // You can change the title on every controller you create.

      $data['template_page'] = 'welcome_message'; // This dashboard would be name of a view and common name a folder.

      $this->load->view('template', $data);
   }

}
```

Example 2 Controller

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {
      // You should be able to pass data as normal

      $data['title'] = 'Dashboard'; // You can change the title on every controller you create.

      $data['template_page'] = 'common/dashboard'; // This dashboard would be name of a view and common name a folder.

      $this->load->view('template', $data);
   }

}
```

Views > template.php

```
<?php

$this->load->view('common/header');

$this->load->view($template_page);

$this->load->view('common/footer');

?>
```

Header views > common > header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    // meta tags
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
    // css links
    // other js links
</head>

<body>
```

Content lets say dashboard views > common > dashboard.php

```
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Footer views > common > footer.php

```
// bootstrap scripts.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one more thing header , footer view always load so   `$this->load->view('common/footer');` and `$this->load->view('common/header');` this write in every view ?

Comment: Just only in the template view more simple that way and you do not have to call them all the time.

Comment: i am confuse i have two view "Report" and "Enquiry" this both need layout so how apply in both and both have also different content and forms

Comment: The code above is just example you need to have a play around with it.